# How to add posts vertically without replacing each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add posts after each other.
I first used this css, but it is adding all posts in the same place.
How can I modify this code to add them after each other (like facebook wall) ?

```
   .post00{
    top:150px;
    left:500px;
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
    height:210px;
    background:white;
    word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    }
```

If I remove the top, left and absolute, the posts will not be aligned in the center.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: remove `top:150px;    left:500px;    position:absolute; ` and add `display:inline-block; text-align:center`

Comment: I added relative instead f absolute, and chnged alittle bit in the top/left , and it worked. Is this fine or should I better go with these solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex box is a great way to handle this. This guide is a great resource.

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.post-list {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.post {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<section class="post-list">
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h3>Hello</h3>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
.post00{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background:white;
    word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

Use Display:flex; to center the content "justify-content;center" to align content center-horizontal and "align-items:center;" to align content center-vertical.